# Simple explanation about loading files into memory

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, memory-management

What does it mean to "load into memory"?

I watched some videos online where they were talking about reducing processing reports times, and they constantly say "you don't want to load a huge file into memory, instead read line by line."

Can I have an example of what loading a file (text file for simplicity) into memory, and an example of handling the file NOT loading it into memory.

What exactly are these benefits they talk about besides processing times being reduced?

Comment: Load into memory: `File.ReadAllLines`, stream lines: `File.ReadLines`. Consider that the file is huge, then you get an `OutOfMemoryException`, if you use a `StreamReader`(or `File.ReadLines`) you just read one line which you can process, then the next line.

Comment: Sometimes it depends on how it is being used.  If a user has to wait while you load many, many lines, then that may be bad.  But once loaded it might be faster to iterate them in memory rather than hitting some drive over and over to read a line.

Comment: Thanks to all for your replies, I've got a better understanding of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When they refer to reading something "into memory" it is simply a way of saying that you are reading it and storing it in a variable (which stores it in memory).

Use ReadAllLines to read the entire file into memory:

```
Dim readText() As String = File.ReadAllLines(path)
```

See [File.ReadAllLines Method (String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1(v=vs.110).aspx)

Use a StreamReader to read a file line by line:

```
Dim sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(path)

Do While sr.Peek() >= 0
    Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadLine())
Loop
sr.Close()
```

See [StreamReader.ReadLine Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline(v=vs.110).aspx)

As the comments above mention, the worst performance implications is that it will simply crash if you try to read too large of a file.  Whether you can save a millisecond or two here or there by reading line-by-line, it depends on a number of factors (size of file, disk latency, etc.)  In general you don't want to be using 100 MB of memory if you don't need to be, so much of the time it's not really about performance, but about not hogging system resources unnecessarily.

If you are processing each line, it's also usually easier to code if you read line-by-line.

Comment: Thanks Tony, I work with StreamReader alot so I now understand it better. I was just thinking into it too much, and expecting it to be more difficult than what I already knew. Thanks for the clarification!